# How long should the Blender BMW demo file take to render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

This is a different question. But I didn’t know where else I should have asked.

I tried rendering the [Blender BMW demo file](https://bit.ly/3bvjJCz) (in cycles, with GPU) and the render took 37 minutes and 48 seconds.

The i tried using CPU instead, and it took 18 minutes.

Is that a very slow render time. If it is, what is considered a “good” render time?

If it is slow, how can I make it faster besides rendering in smaller dimensions and the obvious stuff?

Comment: For reference - On my hardware (CPU: Ryzen3950x - GPU: RTX 2080Ti) CPU render took ~1:46 and GPU Compute took ~6:03 (Though GPU usage never exceeded 10%).

Comment: My PC also needed about 16 min for CPU rendering (8x 64x64px tiles) and the onboard GPU is not supported. More render benchmarks for comparison can be found here: https://opendata.blender.org/

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your hardware. The BMW "blenchmark" should take **however long it takes to render without you modifying the file**.

The idea of such benchmark is for folks to see how their particular hardware compares to other in similar circumstances, with the same scene with the exact same settings.

The results are here:

http://blenchmark.com/gpu-benchmarks

---

Are there ways to speed it up? yes, but that is not the point of said file.

If everybody modifies the file, then there will be way too many variables and the statistics and comparisons for rendering are no longer valid.